# How to replace tab with 4 times space in GIT[Gerrit]?

Tags: git, gerrit

I have a problem with versioning handling in GIT. I am taking over a project from a guy moving to another department and I have noticed that one file is messed up. The 4*space have for some reason been replaced with tabs.

I have done a cherry-pick from the the branch I am taking over and the formatting messes up the version control. I know that there have been modifications in both versions and without proper version control there will be nearly impossible to sort things out. The big problem is that I do not know what have be added or removed after this branch was branched off.

Now I wonder, is there any good way to replace the tabs with 4*space in GIT or Gerrit? So to say, before I do the cherry-pick.

I know it is possible to manually edit a commit in Gerrit, but if possible I would want to do this in some more automatic way.

Comment: Create a new branch, cherry pick what you need, and do a format before you merge back on your old branch.  If that does not work for you, just tell your IDE to treat tabs like four spaces.

Comment: `sed "s/\t/    /g"` (there should be 4 spaces in that last field there)

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen The problem is that I get 3000 lines of conflicts. So basically I have 2 files stacked upon each other with some ===== in between. Since there have been modifications after the first branch off, I need to pick parts from both branches. Or do you mean I should keep the cherry-picked version and remove the other version? Then merge this with another branch after formatting? That might actually work, and does indeed make me feel stupid... Thanks

Comment: @Pockets If I would have the old source file I would be able to do `ctrl+shift+F` in eclipse. Unfortunately this code comes from someone else and due to formatting he was not allowed to push. What I am asking for is basically a way to modify this in gerrit. So to say modfiy his commit and updating it with the same commit ID (in other words, make it look as if this was done in his commit).